# vert.x Postgres connection pool to a multi-instance Aurora (postgres) database cluster

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, vert.x

I have an Amazon Aurora (Postgres) database cluster with multiple read instances.

I am writing a Java client application with a Vert.x database connection `Pool` connecting to this cluster. I would like the pool connections to be evenly distributed among the multiple read instances, but instead all the pool connections connect to a single read instance and don't use the others.

I know why this is happening but I don't know how to fix it. When the database cluster endpoint hostname is resolved at the DNS level, the DNS response randomly picks one of the read instances to respond with. Vert.x is presumably connecting all pool connections with this one DNS response, which points to a single read instance.

My question is what can I do so that the connection pool connections are spread over the multiple database instances.

I would like Vert.x to re-query DNS for each connection in the connection pool. Is that possible?

Alternatively, can the connection pool be configured to open connections on a staggered basis rather than opening all connections at the same time? If I configure a maxLifetime, then all connections will reconnect at the same time, which wouldn't help.

Comment: are you sure it is always the same server? did you create multiple connections from the pool? or used the same connection but made multiple queries